# Can't see my mongo database when using mongo cmd on a Docker container

Tags: mongodb, docker

*Similar to [Can't connect to MongoDB container from other Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53844413/cant-connect-to-mongodb-container-from-other-docker-container) - but answers from this post don't work for me.*

I am new to Docker. Trying to learn it on a typescript/express/mongo/mongoose api example.

What I am trying to do (and having problems with), is to use mongo cmd line on a running mongo container after it has been spun up using `docker compose up`. Even though I have my data nicely persisted on a Docker volume, I don't seem to be able to log into the database using cmd line.

This is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  api:
    container_name: api_ts
    build: .
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - DB_URL=mongodb://myself:pass123@mongo:27017/
    ports:
      - '3131:3131'
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    links: # (seems to be needed)
      - mongo
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo_container
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - mongo_dbv:/data/db
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=myself
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass123
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
volumes:
  mongo_dbv: {}
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json .
RUN npm ci
COPY . .
ENV PORT=3131
EXPOSE 3131
COPY .env ./dist
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

I am running

```
docker compose up -d --build
```

After both services are ready, I do:

```
docker exec -it mongo_container mongo
show dbs
```

...and the output of the last cmd is empty

(same occurs when trying to follow the answers in the post mentioned above)

I am sure the database contains data, because I am able to verify it using REST client.

Also, I am a bit puzzled - and maybe this is somehow connected - why there is no indication, either in docker-compose.yml or in Dockerfile, of the **database name** which I am using. I would expect it to be part of `show dbs` output. Despite that, my api runs just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listing databases requires authentication

```
docker exec -it mongo_container mongo -u myself -p pass123
```

Now you can list databases

```
> show dbs
admin   0.000GB
config  0.000GB
local   0.000GB
```

Note: mongo should show you warning that "mongo" shell has been superseded by "mongosh". When you use mongosh, a proper authentication error would be shown on the database listing attempt.

Comment: Yep, this is exactly what happens :) thank you. Turns out, I have all my data in `test` db. Need to figure out how to better configure the container and my app to explicitly name the db.